# Always serve index.html when page not found

Tags: asp.net-core, react-router, kestrel

I am about to deploy a React app using react-router in our intranet. I am using Kestrel without a reverse proxy.

When I start browsing the site by typing https://myserver/, the page gets served and I can click links which take me to https://myserver/subpage, but subpage does not exist inside wwwroot, only react-router uses this to determine the contents to display. Now if the user presses the browser's reload button, a 404 is returned.

Should I configure Kestrel to serve index.html in case the requested resource is not found? If so, yes? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question on how to solve this with Kestrel.